Elementary question on conics regarding matrix form

Let $A,A'$ be two non-null symmetric matrices. Furthermore, suppose that $XAX^T=0; XA'X^T=0$ define the same locus in $\mathbb{P}^2({\mathbb{C}})$; then show that $A$ and $A'$ are scalar multiples of one another.

I could diagonalize $A,A'$ and I would get equations of the form $ax^2+by^2+cz^2=0$; but I haven't arrived at any conclusion. Any suggestions?
EDIT: Writing the two equations above as irreducible homogeneous polynomials and applying the 'Nullstellensatz' would lead to $P/Q=k; \; k \in \mathbb{C^*}$, but this is far too advanced for the purpose and I'm not even sure about this conclusion
